# Unable to install any packages in RStudio

Tags: r, package

I tried to install packages in R but every time it gives me an error message.
For example when I try to stall: install.packages("dplyr"), the error messages:

```
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [capture.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Users/hemenglu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rlang’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/hemenglu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘ellipsis’ ...
** package ‘ellipsis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c dots.c -o dots.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [dots.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ellipsis’
* removing ‘/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/ellipsis’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/ellipsis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ellipsis’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘vctrs’ ...
** package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c altrep-rle.c -o altrep-rle.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [altrep-rle.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vctrs’
* removing ‘/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘vctrs’ is not available for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘pillar’ is not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tibble’ is not available for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/Users/hlu/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/dplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/nq/w5bk18255kbgczcmwhqlmqh00000gn/T/RtmpNFakPn/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

can you please help me look at it and see what's missing there?

Comment: You seem to be compiling packages from source, in which case you will need the Xcode command-line tools (which can be installed with `xcode-select --install`).

Comment: Or just install the binary versions and not source versions with `install.packages("dplyr", type="binary")`. It's often not really necessary to compile yourself on Mac or Windows. Or when it asks if you want to compile from source, say no.